# Cybernetic T-rex comic?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I vaguely recall reading/browsing a black and white(?) comic in the early '90s or late '80s featuring a partially robotic tyrannosaurus.  Could it have been anything other than Dino Riders?

It was something like that, but more focused on its head, which I believe was damaged on the right side, like a Terminator.

[image: Dino Riders #1, 1989]

Answer (score 5):

I do not really recall Dino Riders, but in the 90's there was one comic I remember with Dinosaurs that were partially robotic, particularly a T-rex.  In Book four of Scud the disposable Assassin, Voodoo Ben Franklin has an army of Zombie Dinosaurs and has some of them with cybernetic attachments, including a large T-rex.
For reference:
http://www.scud.com/pages/books/scudFour.html

Comment: That might be it! That 1994 eye/cam looks closer than the lasers in [this](http://media.comicvine.com/uploads/0/4/61545-4223-94540-1-dino-riders_super.jpg) 1989 comic, but it doesn't look very robotic otherwise... I think the image i remember was a full page one on the left side.
Does Scud or similar feature bottom right panels where a guy attempts suicide but shoots the robot half of his head that turns out to be bulletproof?

Comment: After reading that Scud issue, i can definitely say that my comic was less angular and more serious.

Answer (score 2):

This might be it, but i think the T-Rex had more skin than that:

[Zero X](http://www.technodelic.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/Upload05/ZeroXPt3.htm): TV21 & TV Tornado - 1969
and Countdown - 1971

Journey To The Planet Of Bones (Story Eighteen)
Writer: 'James Freeman' (Angus P. Allan).
Artist: Mike Noble. 2 pages, colour.

[image: The Planet of Bones]

> A huge skeleton hand erupts from the surface, and tries to grab Greg.
>   Paul blasts it with his laser, and it drops the copilot to vanish back
>   into the depths. Pierce surmises disease or disaster overtook the
>   primitive animals, leading to a new form of evolution - independent
>   living bones. It was a stray skull which killed Vatski and destroyed
>   the Zenith 4, but Paul feels they should destroy the pool to prevent
>   further incidents. But as he speaks, the pool erupts, and a full skull
>   and skeleton emerges. Pierce admits he is wrong, and that bones are
>   not the end of the evolution but the beginning. A complete living
>   skeleton is the birth of a new species, and a whole race may be
>   spawned by the pool at any minute...